# COUNT for NULL or 0 group using a join

Tags: mysql, join, count

I am trying to determine a count for a grouped column with no entries, I almost get the results i require except when the COUNT is 0 or NULL. Query I am using is below.

```
SELECT count(t2.users) as user_count, t3.user_group
FROM db.table1 t1
inner join db.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
inner join db.table3 t3 on t1.id2 = t3.id
group by t3.user_group
order by t3.user_group;
```

Results
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NkMb.png][1]

Results ide like to see
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Apt.png][2]

Comment: ALways best to copy/paste even results, as it helps to keep the question integrity which can be broken when images are deleted and the question remains

Comment: Show tables structures. Especially the info about does the fields used in a query are unique.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: When this is clear it will be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the joins with `table3` and use `left` joins instead of `inner` (at least for the join between `table1` and `table2`):

```
SELECT count(t2.users) as user_count, t3.user_group
FROM db.table3 t3
left join db.table1 t1 on t1.id2 = t3.id
left join db.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
group by t3.user_group
order by t3.user_group;
```

Comment: The desured result shows that there are duplicates in at least one table. If there are dups in 2 or 3 tables the result will be wrong.

Comment: This is something that the OP will see in the results. This code solves the problem as expressed in the question: *I almost get the results i require except when the COUNT is 0 or NULL* by doing left joins. If after that the counters do not return the correct results then the code should be modified.

Answer (score 0):

try Left Join Instead of using Inner Join. Generally Inner Join Only Returns Values that is Available in both Right and Left Table. Means If Some record is available is a left table and no relevant information available in right Table then Your Select Query Returns empty Record Set. All Rows as Requested.

so Change Your Query as

```
      SELECT count(t2.users) as user_count, t3.user_group FROM db.table3 t3
              left join db.table1 t1 on t1.id2 = t3.id
              left join db.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
              group by t3.user_group
              order by t3.user_group;
```

Comment: ```If You use Left Join Either Left table or right Table having a value means select Query Returns Some Value as your Required Format.```. This is wrong, left join includes all rows from left table with null right table columns in case join condition doesn't match with any row in right table.

Comment: S bro . Sorry I m also trying to convey these Message. Thanks Bro @ Mohd Waseem